# Get the update server name using command line

Tags: command-line, update-manager

How to get the update server name using command line?

I know I could read it from the source list file, for example:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

gives:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted multiverse
```

Then I use the US server.

But how can I do that in more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a fine tuning of your approach:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep deb | cut -d' ' -f2
```

The `cut -d' ' -f2` part cuts out the second column from the line containing the word `deb`.

Comment: This will show other repositories also with much `deb`  lines. here is sample of the output

Comment: `deb
deb
deb
deb
deb
deb
deb
deb
deb
deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

Comment: You could change the grep expression to something more useful, e.g. `'restricted multiverse'`. Or you can make a more complex solution using `awk`, but I can't be of much help with that.

Comment: still malformed output `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep "restricted multiverse" | cut -d' ' -f2
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

Comment: Could you add the whole sources.list file to the question? In a link perhaps.

Comment: I tried using grep and cut much times, i advise you to search for other possible solution, i doubt the list would help, moreover I have many systems each has different source list and even each with different Ubuntu version

Comment: you could try using the `-m` parameter to limit the result to only the first few matches. for example using `grep -m 1 deb` will only show the first matching result

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--print-uris` option of `apt-get`

```
$ sudo apt-get --print-uris update||grep Packages.bz2|awk '{print $2}'|sed -e 's/_ubuntu_dists_vivid\(-\|_\)\?/ /' -e 's/_binary-.*_Packages//'|sort -u
```

This **will not** update the package list

Comment: This shows the URL of packages indicated in the command and not the update server.

Comment: You get the update from the same server. What do you call update server ?? Then try `apt-get --print-uris update`

Comment: The output is too big with malformed. I just need the name not the whole list. I could read the sources.list instead it still easier to read

Comment: @Maythux I have updated the answer to a shorter output

Answer (score 0):

I got this idea from the answer by meskobalazs.

You can try running this command in the terminal

```
server=$(cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -m 1 deb\ h) ; echo ${server:11:2}
```

`grep -m 1` returns only the first match. `${server:11:2}` returns the first two letters after `deb http://`.

when I run the command, the output is `sg` cut out from `deb http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted`